Travelling to UK with pending assault charge?
Hi I'm travelling to the UK because my grandma passed away - travelling from Canada.  I have a pending assault charge from July that is still going through the courts - no other criminal record or actual convictions.  Will I be able to enter the UK cleanly (without question)?
Update: also, I'll add I'm a Canadian Citizen since 2003 and have no problems flying within Canada
Edit:  to clarify, I am specifically interested in whether the UK border services will have any issues with a pending charge?

I would think, until convicted, you are innocent of any charges.  UK should let you in.
However, the Canadian authorities may not allow you to travel depending upon your status with them.

What is your citizenship? If not a Canadian citizen, what is your legal status in Canada?

@DavidRecallsMonica I'm a Canadian Citizen since 2003 and I've had no issues flying domestically within Canada

Do you have bail conditions?

@WeatherVane nothing serious - only to stay away from the "victim" and to not possess firearms, weapons, etc

you should probably ask your lawyer if you are allowed to leave Canada or not, if you have not already done so

@mlc I can leave Canada no problem according to my lawyer.  To clarify:  My original question is about the UK border services and will they have any issue with a pending charge?

I applaud your courage to ask this question.
